# Show more/less items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, usability

I've got a set of elements and I don't want to show them all at once.
My problem is that I've got to use this a series of times in the same page.
Do you guys know jQuery plugin that does what I've written?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $lis = $('.addfilter'); 
    min = 2;
    max = $lis.length;
    var visible = min;

    function showUpToIndex(index) {
        $lis.hide();
        $lis.slice(0, index).show();
    }

    function disableButtons(){
        if (visible >= max){
            visible = max;
            $('#more').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#more').show();
        }
        if (visible <= min){
            visible = min;
            $('#less').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#less').show();
        }
    }

    showUpToIndex(visible);
    disableButtons();

    $('#more').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        visible = visible + 5;
        disableButtons();  
        showUpToIndex(visible);
    });

    $('#less').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        visible = visible - 5;
        disableButtons();     
        showUpToIndex(visible);
    });
});
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cUUfS/179/

Thanks!

Comment: Well, do you want to show 5 more divs on click of `#more` and hide 5 on click of `#less`?

Comment: Whats the problem with using it multiple times on the same page?
Wrap it in an object `var myPlugin= function(){};` and create multiple instances of it whenever needed.

Comment: What do I do with the show less/more spans? Should my function add them after the last option span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try these,

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/

https://github.com/mfarid/readmore-readless

This may help I hope

Comment: Nope, that truncates text (looks like another implementation of https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-expander). I don't want to truncate sutff, only hide and show.

Comment: Ok. What about this one?

http://www.joshuawinn.com/examples/hide-max-li/jquery-hide-max-list-items.html

Comment: Good approach, but there are two things. First, it just works with lists. Second, it does not show items by stages (show 10 items when pressed for first time and then 10 more).